# How to schedule node field from a specific content type for a particular time period in drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I am looking to hide specific field from a content type for a particular period of time to authenticated user in drupal 8.

For example - From article content type , body field should be visible after a specific date for authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module called [scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler) that publish the node for particular period of time. I believe that there is no module that would do the same for the special field (at least I am not aware of it).

The simplest solution that I can think of is that you create two date fields for a selected content type (start and end date) or use one date range field. Than in twig template use the if statement that would check if current date is bigger than start date and lower than end date. I suggest using timestamp format to avoid any unexpected results. Inside the if statement put the code that render field/field value and you will get the expected result.